# What is the appropriate action to take when nuisance comment flags are declined?

Tags: support, comments, flagging

I raised the "no longer needed" flag on the following comment

> If we start inferring from the career of campaign managers... Manafort served Ukraine's pro-Kremlin and anti-NATO president Yanukovych for a long time before becoming Trump's campaign manager. So we can probably jump too far in conclusions on that line of reasoning.

to [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/47312/13162).  Clearly the comment contains no suggestions on how the answer maybe improved.  Instead of getting erased, it was upvoted.  There is no option to bring the comment to a moderator's attention.

Should I be bring the question to the moderators' attention in such a case?

I am not even complaining about the fact that people are downvoting the answer despite the fact that it provides research on the historical question to which it responds.  Based on experience, I expect the rules not to be followed on this site.

I only want to know what is the proper way to handle the nuisance comments which are not removed by the community.

Answer (score 8):

The comment provides valid criticism to the first part of the answer, about Bill Clinton's associate. That part is a bit speculative and does not answer the question. The question asks about presidents, specifically. If that wasn't the case, it would probably get closed as either too broad or primarily opinion-based.

The comment may not provide explicit guidance on how to improve the answer, but it certainly isn't a nuisance. Unfortunately, it's not always possible to improve everything that may be wrong in an answer. Sometimes critisism is all you can offer.

Comment: Do you mean that the answer was speculative or the sources?  I actually didn't express any opinion of my own there.  It was the opinion expressed, and somewhat supported by facts, by the contemporary NYTimes and Times magazine.  I quotes 2 of the most popularly read, at the time, media sources which were reporting on the events described.  In fact, my quotes were actually milder than their reporting was.  If two wildly-read media sources do not demonstrate "a common understanding", I am not sure what would.  Again, what do you *mean* by "speculative"?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the standard "sometimes criticism is all you can offer" result in a forum?  If there is no guidance on how to improve the answer, then the comment does not contribute to the mandate of making the site the most informative question/answer repository that it can be.

Comment: Thirdly, you aren't really answering the question asked here.  You've questioned it's premise.  But that's a separate issue.  For future reference, what should be done about a nuisance comment which is wrongly maintained by the community?

Comment: Nuisance comments are not maintained by the community @grovkin. That is a non-issue. Flag them. If they are actually nuisance, they will be removed. If not, they'll stick around. That's all there is to it.